# Every imported function comes up as "undefined", though the import is clearly being made

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I've downloaded `d3` from here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.js and have included it in my `/static` folder.

**/static/graph.js**

```
import * as d3 from "/static/d3.js"
export function graph() {
    d3.select("#classname");
    console.log("Selected");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import {graph} from "/static/graph.js"
            graph()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, I recieve the error `d3.select is not a function.`

- The setup of the `/static` folder is sound; if I change the string referencing either of the .js files, I'm (appropriately) met with a `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: ...` That is, with the strings as they are, we can see and serve the files appropriately (further: the response from the network is 304, indicating the cached files match what the server is serving).
- D3 is being loaded *in some way*. If I place a `debugger;` inside of the `graph()` function, go to the dev. console and type `d3`, I am able to scroll through an autocomplete list of all functions defined in D3 (including `select`). But, something like `d3.select`, returns `Undefined`. So D3 is being loaded enough to autocomplete, but everything is coming up as undefined. The variable itself is of type `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"` which is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) (though I am not sure what to make of said documentation)
- On the other hand, placing a `debugger;` statement in `index.html` shows that `d3` seems to work as intended, even though this is not where it's being imported.

Why is `d3.select` not a function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the issue here is, you are attempting to load a module, but there are ES6 Modules, and there are UMD Modules. D3.js is a UMD Module.

UMD modules, are "bootstrapped" to hook into the "window" or "global" object. UMD modules, evolved during a time, where exactly how "Modules" would work was in flux, anyways it's a very fascinating topic and I would recommend reading up on it sometime...

So instead of

```
import * as d3 from "/static/d3.js"
```

you should do

```
import "/static/d3.js"
```

Now you will be able to use D3, as it has been attached to the "window" object.

So with that being said your setup would look like:

```
// index.html
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import {graph} from "/static/graph.js"
            graph()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And

```
// static/graph.js
import "/static/d3.js" // Now loaded as UMD module
export function graph() {
    d3.select("#classname");
    console.log("Selected");
}
```

That would work.

As a side-note, this is the part of the D3 Module, which does the bootstrapping and attaches D3 to the "window" object.

```
...
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
        (global = global || self, factory(global.d3 = global.d3 || {})); // <-- the "magic" part.
}(this, function (exports) { 
     /* 
          THE REST OF THE MODULE SOURCE GOES HERE 
          all 18,561 lines of it...
     */ 
}));
```

Comment: omg you're a lifesaver. I had no clue that these modules were different

Comment: np :-), I just added a small snippet to my answer, which highlights, the UMD "bootstraper"  bits.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue trying to import the [React CDN Links](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html) as an ES6 Module, and this is the only answer that worked for me. If I could upvote you 1,000 times I would.